# how to calculate sum in last td input

Tags: php, jquery, html

**My form**
[image]

Please see the above image for better understanding.

i want to get sum of first two td in last td(total) for each row .
current jquery code in this code i was trying to get value of td(total) id

```
function foc(id){
  $id=id;
  $par=$(id).closest('tr').children(find('td:last')).children('input #total').val();
  console.log($par);
}
```

and php code for printing table is

```
  for ( $i =1 ; $i <=5; $i++)
     { 
      $name=$i+1;
      echo '<tr >';
      echo '<td><input type="hidden" value="10148301'. $i.'">10148301'. $i.'</td>';
             for ( $j = 1; $j<=$count+1; $j++) 
                 {
                    if ($j==$count+1) 
                        {
                          $name="total[]";
                          $class="total";
                          $on="";
                         }
                     else
                        {
                           $name="any";
                           $on='onfocus="foc(this.id);"';
                            $class="score";
                         }
                     echo '<td>';
                     echo '<input type="text" style="width:50px;" '.$on.'  id="'.$class.'" class="form-control" name="'.$name.'">';
                     echo '</td> ';
            }
                         echo '</tr>';
```

Comment: Do you want to calculate it when you entered the values or do you have a button?

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: i want it to be calculated when i enter values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One approach is to use jQuery to bind keyup events to your text inputs:

```
$('tr > td').not(':last-child').on('keyup', 'input[type="text"]', function() {
    var parentRow = $(this).parents('tr');
    var q1Value = parentRow.find('td:eq(0) > input').val();
    var q2Value = parentRow.find('td:eq(1) > input').val();
    var totalInput = parentRow.find('td:last-child > input');
    if (q1Value.length && q2Value.length) {
        totalInput.val(parseInt(q1Value, 10) + parseInt(q2Value, 10));
     } else {
        totalInput.val('');
    }
});
```

You can find a barebones example CodePen [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oxQWer).

Comment: thnx bro :) but i manually wrote it and its working now
     ` var tbl = $('#fq');
        tbl.find('tr').each(function () {
            var sum = 0;
            $(this).find('#score').each(function () {
                if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                    sum += parseInt(this.value);
                }
            });

            $(this).find('#total').val(sum);
        });`